# Error while evaluating TimerFcn for timer.. Too many input arguments. MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

The problem with a timer in the MatLab App Designer.
It return an error: "Error while evaluating TimerFcn for timer..  Too many input arguments"

my code:

```
app.t.TimerFcn = @app.timerFunction;
```

```
function timerFunction(app, ~, ~)

    %something

end
```

I've been looking for a solution. I also tried this:

```
app.t.TimerFcn =  @(app, ~, ~)app.timerFunction
timerFunction(app, ~, ~)
```

```
app.t.TimerFcn =  @(~,~)app.timerFunction
timerFunction(app)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Adriaan It's useful in cases like this where MATLAB is going to give you multiple inputs since it's an event, but you don't care about them.

Comment: @Adriaan: if you write a callback function, it needs to have the right signature, the right number of input arguments. If you don’t need all those arguments in your function, you can use `~` to avoid naming them. This is recommended syntax.

Comment: Please show the full stack trace from the error message. Maybe this is about a different TimerFunction, or maybe you’re calling a different function than you think. The timer callback expects two input arguments.

Comment: @Cris Luengo Too many input arguments.
Error while evaluating TimerFcn for timer 'timer-61'

Comment: `timer-61` indicates you have constructed 61 timers. Are they all still up? This might be a different timer altogether that's erroring out. Consider clearing them, to avoid confusion: type `clear all` at the MATLAB command prompt (or restart MATLAB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The found solution is:

callback function:

```
function timerFunction(app)
    % stuff
end
```

timer settings

```
app.t.TimerFcn =  @(x,y)timerFunction(app);
```

Comment: I think you must have had wires crossed whilst originally debugging this issue. Doing this should be equivalent to your original `@app.timerFunction` with `function timerFunction(app,~,~)`, or equivalent to replacing `x` and `y` with `~`. In future, including a [mcve] in your question helps clarify specific issues.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have reduced the code for a better understanding:) Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `varargin` and worry less about the number of input arguments which the event is throwing, i.e.

```
function timerFunction( app, varargin )
    % stuff
end
```

This will also help you debug and see how many inputs MATLAB is in fact trying to pass, by looking at the contents of `varargin`.

In a similar way to your other attempts you can use `varargin` in your function handle too, although this doesn't allow for the same debugging

```
app.t.TimerFcn = @(varargin) app.timerFunction;
```

Comment: Just tried it. Didn't help(

But if I put `dbstop()` in the `function timerFunction( app, varargin )`, it says  "Not enough input arguments"

Comment: @William Where does it say that? If you can stop *inside* the callback then are you getting the error for your call to `app.readAppData`? Looking at your question again it looks like you're passing `app` in twice, you should do **either** `app.readAppData(app.serRead)` **or** `readAppData(app, app.serRead)`. If this is actually your issue please let me know and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Suddenly, I have found a solution...But I really don't understand what happens here. 
`app.t.TimerFcn = @(x,y)timerFunction(app);`
`function timerFunction(app)`

and you were right, there was one extra error in the function's body.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and just wanted to let you know that this error can be a bit misleading.
In my case, I called a function via a timer, and I had a normal function call in that callback function:

```
T = timer('TimerFcn', @(~,~) this.callback, 'StartDelay', waitTime);
```

...

```
function callback(this)
  ...
  this.doStuff(x,y);
end

function doStuff(x, y)
  ...
end
```

which of course should have been:

```
function doStuff(this, x, y)
  ...
end
```

So the problem didn't have anything to do with the timer, but was just an error in some other part that was executed by the timer callback function.